# Sampling with weight for 1 number

Tags: r, random

I want to sample from a big pool of numbers e.g. `-2000:5000`.
I would like thought to set the weight for a certain number to `80%`.
Everything other possibility should be equal for every other number.

Doing this for a small sample is easy:
`sample(-2:2, 10, replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.05, 0.05, 0.80, 0.05, 0.05))`
this would output:

> [1]  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0

How can I do this for a big range of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manipulate your probability vector pragmatically. So you have

```
values <- -2:2
special_value <- 0
```

Then you can do

```
probs <- rep(1, length(values))
probs[values==special_value] <- (length(values )-1)*.8/(1-.8)
```

Then use

```
sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE, prob=probs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a smaller code to tell you the truth. E.g 
`sample(-2:2, 10, replace = TRUE, prob={0:0.8})`
How come they didn't integrate this into sample ...

Comment: you could also do `probs <- ifelse(values == special_value, 0.8, 0.2/(length(x) - 1))` if you wanted to shorten the code slightly...

Answer (score 2):

You only need to run a separate vector with all the probabilities. Take on the account that when you create the probabilities vector, you can use a logic test to define "p1 = 0.8" if it is my desired number and "p2 = 0.2/n" in any other case. The code run as follows:

```
n <- 37 # your num
x <- -100:1000 # your sequence
probs <- ifelse(x == n, 0.8, (1 - 0.8) /length(x) ) # determine probabilities taking on account they have to add up to 1
sum(probs)
sample(x = x, size = 1000, prob = probs)
```

Let me know if it helps.